# How can I exclude script tags and style tags from a TextField that will turn eventually to a plain html code

Tags: python, html, django

I need a way that removes Script tags and Style tags from a textarea since it runs when I post a post.

When I post something as a Post-it should turn everything from HTML tags to plain text that HTML was applied on, therefore, script tags and style tags will be applied as well, which is quite unprofessional and risky.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable = False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.message_html = misaka.html(self.message)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:single', kwargs = {'username': self.user.username,'pk':self.pk})
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        unique_together = ['user', 'message']
```

I expect the output not to be applied or built, instead, I expect it to delete the ,  and show everything inside as plain text.

(Update)
I wanted the user to be able to use html tags within his post but I did not want him to use the script and style tags, I managed to make it work by writing this following.
in Posts views.py

```py
class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):
    fields = ('message', 'group')
    model = models.Post

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit = False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            # is Superuser
            self.object.message_html = misaka.html(self.object.message)
        else:
            # Not superuser
            self.object.message_html = str(self.object.message).replace("<script>", "").replace("</script>", "").replace("<style>", "").replace('</style>', "")
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: When you render `post.message` in a template, Django by default doesn't mark it as safe, so it wouldn't be applied anyway. It will just render as plain text and you'd see the actual tags. What do you mean by "script tags and style tags will be applied"?

Comment: I managed to do it successfully by replacing the script tags and the style tags of the stringified message with nothing which solved it.
but the thing is if the user capitalized the script tag by any way he will be able to run the code, got any way to solve it?